# Column Unknown Firebird Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm trying to make a GUI with python and tkinter for a firebird database. When I try to write the input from boxes into the databse, I get error

`fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while preparing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -206\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -206\n- Column unknown\n- NUMBER\n- At line 1, column 99', -206, 335544569)`

This is the code for the submit operation:

```python
simnumbber = "SIM NUMBER"

def submit():

    #  Database connection in the function
    conn = fdb.connect(
    host='localhost', database='C:/SIMCARDS.fdb', user='user', password='password')
    # Cursor
    cur = conn.cursor()
    
    
    # Insert Into table
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO table ("NUMBER", simnumbber, "OPERATOR", "TYPE", "TARIFF", "DATA", "STATUS") VALUES (:number, :simnumber, :operator, :type, :tariff, :data, :status);""",
    {
        'number': simnumber.get(),
        'simnumber': cardnumber.get(),
        'operator': operator.get(),
        'type': type.get(),
        'tariff': tariff.get(),
        'data': data.get(),
        'status': status.get()  

    })

    # Commit Cahanges
    conn.commit()
    # Close connection
    conn.close()

    # Clear Textboxes
    simnumber.delete(0, END)
    cardnumber.delete(0, END)
    operator.delete(0, END)
    type.delete(0, END)
    tariff.delete(0, END)
    data.delete(0, END)
    status.delete(0, END)
```

Comment: And what is the structure of your table? If it says *there's no such column*, you should trust your database. But I think the reason is quoted identifiers: they are treated as is, and quoted uppercase name does not equal to quoted lowercase name. So my advice is: get rid of the quoted identifiers in every database design to make it less buggy.

Comment: Thank you. You mean the quoted names of the columns in the insert into query, right? I did try the query without them and the result was the same, unfortinately. As for the names in the data base - they are upper case. And for the structure - it has only one table with the columns provided in the code.

Comment: What is the DDL of the table, please be exact, a table created with column `"number"`, does not have a column `"NUMBER"` (but `"number"`), while a table created with `number` (no quotes), has a column `NUMBER` (and `"NUMBER"` or `number` will match, but not `"number"`), given the fact that unquoted object names in any case are stored in uppercase and match columns stored in uppercase, while quoted object names are stored as-is.

Comment: If you can't provide the DDL of the table, then provide the result of `select rdb$relation_name, rdb$field_name from rdb$relation_fields where rdb$relation_name = <table-name>`; where `<table-name>` must match the exact table name, so a `table` (unquoted) is `'TABLE'`, while `"table"` (quoted) is `'table'`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry for the long time to respond. Here is the DDL:
[link](https://pastebin.pl/view/2a00a3c1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving this here for anyone that has to do something like this. The problem was with the parameters I provided in the SQL query in the VALUES clause. Firebird didn't know what ':number' was. So the fixed query is this:
`cur.execute("""INSERT INTO cards (number,"SIM NUMBER",OPERATOR,TYPE,TARIFF,DATA,STATUS) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);""", (simnumber.get(),cardnumber.get(),operator.get(), type.get(), tariff.get(), data.get(), status.get()))`